# Как сократить повторяющийся фрагмент кода?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, где много повторяющихся переменных и вызовов функций. Как можно его написать покороче? `/* Учусь js сильно не ругайте... */`

Фрагмент кода :

```
    function getInterval() {
        if (StateStnum_1 != stnum_1 ) {
            StateStnum_1++;
            if (StateStnum_1 === 10) {
                StateStnum_1 = 0;
            }

            flip('hoursUp' + 1, 'hoursDown' + 1, StateStnum_1, 'Single/Up/' + 2 + '/', 'Single/Down/' + 1 + '/');
        }

        if (StateStnum_2 != stnum_2 ) {
            StateStnum_2++;
            if (StateStnum_2 === 10) {
                StateStnum_2 = 0;
            }

            flip('hoursUp' + 2, 'hoursDown' + 2, StateStnum_2, 'Single/Up/' + 2 + '/', 'Single/Down/' + 1 + '/');               
        }
```

[Код полностью](https://jsfiddle.net/Valeriy1996/uk95046b/5/) на фидле.

Comment: Все ваши переменные с цифровыми суффиксами в массив и обработку завернуть в цикл, как вариант...
Блок if (StateStnum_1 === 10)  заменяется на StateStnum_1 = StateStnum_1 % 10 в данном случае...

Comment: @Dementiy1999 А что означает "минифицировать"? Я сначала подумал, что нужно его мумифицировать!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы динамически составлять имя, это должно быть свойство объекта. В вашем случае переменные `StateStnum_*` и `stnum_*` хочется получать через некий параметр, `id`, который приобретает значения 1,2,3 и 4. Чтобы это провернуть, надо знать объект, которому они принадлежат. Тогда обращаться к ним можно так: `obj['StateStnum_' + id]` – т.е. вычислять имя! И обычный синтакс для статичных имён: `obj.StateStnum_1`

Если вы не объявляли эти переменные через `var`, то они, на самом деле – св-ва объекта `window`: `window.StateStnum_1`. Предположу, что вы, как хороший программист, не плодите глобальных переменных, а создали где-то объект `obj`, и все эти переменные сделали его свойствами. Тогда повторяющийся код можно написать как ф-ю от единственного параметра:

```
function check(id)
    if ( obj["StateStnum_"+id] == obj["stnum_" + id]) return;

    obj["StateStnum_" + id]++;
    if (obj["StateStnum_" + id] === 10) obj["StateStnum_" + id] = 0;
    flip('hoursUp' + id, 'hoursDown' + id, obj["StateStnum_" + id], 'Single/Up/2/', 'Single/Down/1/');
}
```

И повторяющиеся вызовы будут выглядеть весьма лаконично:

```
function getInterval() {
    check(1);
    check(2);
    check(3);
    check(4);
    // ...
```